# rails view sort model by various category

Tags: view, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, parameters

In my artist index I have this code that allows a user to search for an artist and then the page will just display the results rather than all artists.

```
<%= form_tag(artists_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Artists" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

This works because in my controller I have:

```
def index
    if params[:search]
        @artists = Artist.search(params[:search].titleize).order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @artists = Artist.all.order(:name)
    end
end
```

But now I want to add buttons in my view to sort by other categories, such as highest average score, most reviews, etc. What's the best way to do this similar to how I did the form, so that when they click the link it will toss in a parameter to the index in controller and reload the page?

Comment: May be the options by which you want to filter search results can be given as select options and while clicking on search after choosing the filter option, it can also be sent to the index method of controller and show results based on that.

Comment: I would implement a basic search that only searches for the name of the artist and an advanced search with a lot more options. Within the advanced search you can use dropdowns, sliders or whatever else to make searching for anything in particular a breeze. All params will be send to your controller. However, I would not implement the advanced search functionality within your index action. I'd prefer to use a module, concern or plain old ruby object to keep your controller skinny.

Answer (score 0):

First let's refactor this code a little bit and add the changes:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :search, ->(keyword) {where('name ilike ?', "%#{keyword.titleize}%") if search.present?}
end

def index
  params[:order] =  params[:search] ? :created_at : (params[:order] || :name)
  @artists = Artist.search(params[:search]).order("#{order_column} DESC")
end
```

in your view, if you display a column names then beside each one display an Arrow for sorting and clicking it will toggle sort to be desc or asc for this column, if you don't have columns name in your view then add a select dropdown with columns name and on change submit the form:

```
<%= form_tag(artists_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, placeholder: "Search Artists" %>
  <%= select_tag :order, options_for_select([ ['Created At', :created_at],  ['Name', :name ], :name) %> 
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```